# Magento 2 topmenu Use of columnslimit

Tags: magento2, topmenu

```
<?php $columnsLimit = $block->getColumnsLimit() ?: 0; ?>
```

What is the use of $columnsLimit in Magento theme topmenu.phtml?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the maximum depth for categories as controlled by
Config -> Catalog -> Catalog -> Category Top Navigation

Basically how many levels deep the navigation goes into your category structure.

0 in this case meaning no limit.